Green synthesis of different sizes of zinc oxide nanorods using leaf extracts
Zinc oxide nanorods have been green synthesised using various leaf extracts, such as Thymus kotschyanus and Agaricus bisporus.
I want to synthesis Zinc oxide nanorods of different sizes using a leaf extract, and then investigate the nanorods for their antibacterial activity. Usually, these leaf extracts have compounds which act as capping and stabilizing agents, thereby aiding the nanorod formation.
Now, how do I choose a leaf extract and vary a certain variable(temperature, quantity, etc.), to develop Zinc oxide nanorods of different sizes? Any approaches?

No given procedures in the sources you implicitly refer to?

Souring those leaf extracts is a bit of a constraint for me. Also nothing is specifically mentioned about nanorods with different sizes.
